# Связать всех пользователей системы с моделью в Django

Tags: python, django

Не могу понять в джанге 1.11 один момент.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User.objects.all()
```

это вернет нам всех юзеров в проекте нашем.
У меня есть моделька, "подарок", кроме описательных моментов у него есть кому подарить подарок и я хочу чтобы можно было выбирать одного или нескольких юзеров, которые зареганы в системе, т.е. чтобы выбор был с `User.objects.all()`, как это реализовать что-то не пойму.
Т.е. нельзя создать модель человек просто, так как подарок нужно дарить именно тому, кто есть в системе...
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал что-то вроде

```
class Item(models.Model):
    ...
    # Поля даримого предмета

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'предмет'
        verbose_name_plural = 'предметы'


class Gift(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, verbose_name='Предмет')
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Отправитель')
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Получатель')
    sent = models.DateTimeField('Отправлено')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'подарок'
        verbose_name_plural = 'подарки'
```

Но можно и проще

```
class Gift(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, verbose_name='Получатели')
```